# how to get keypoints from specific area opmecv android

Tags: android, opencv, image-processing, opticalflow

i want to build an application like [this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_4hA36nXRjw). I want to draw keypoints from the rectangle drawn here. How can i achieve that? I want to detect object coming in that red circle, kindly help me achieve that.
Here is my code`.

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements CvCameraViewListener2 {

```
private MatOfPoint features;
private Mat                  mIntermediateMat;
private Mat                  mRgba;
private Mat                  mGray;
private org.opencv.core.Size                 wsize;
Mat                          descriptors ;
FeatureDetector              featureDetector;
MatOfKeyPoint                keyPoints;
DescriptorExtractor          descriptorExtractor;
DescriptorMatcher            descriptorMatcher;

protected static final String TAG = null;
private BaseLoaderCallback mLoaderCallBack = new BaseLoaderCallback(this){

     public void onManagerConnected(int status) {
            switch (status) {
                case LoaderCallbackInterface.SUCCESS: {
                    Log.i(TAG, "OpenCV Loaded Successfully");
                    mOpenCvCameraView.enableView();
                    break;
                }
                default: {
                    super.onManagerConnected(status);
                }
            }
        }
};
private JavaCameraView mOpenCvCameraView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mOpenCvCameraView = (JavaCameraView) findViewById(R.id.main_activity_surface_view);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setVisibility(SurfaceView.VISIBLE);
    mOpenCvCameraView.setCvCameraViewListener(this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    OpenCVLoader.initAsync(OpenCVLoader.OPENCV_VERSION_3_1_0, this, mLoaderCallBack);
}

public void onDestroy() {
    super.onDestroy();
    if (mOpenCvCameraView != null) {
        mOpenCvCameraView.disableView();
    }
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStarted(int width, int height) {
    mRgba = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mIntermediateMat = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC4);
    mGray = new Mat(height, width, CvType.CV_8UC1);
    featureDetector=FeatureDetector.create(FeatureDetector.DYNAMIC_ORB);
    descriptorExtractor=DescriptorExtractor.create(DescriptorExtractor.ORB);
    descriptorMatcher= DescriptorMatcher.create(6);
    keyPoints = new MatOfKeyPoint();
    descriptors = new Mat();
    mIntermediateMat = new Mat();
    features = new MatOfPoint();
}

@Override
public void onCameraViewStopped() {


}

@Override
public Mat onCameraFrame(CvCameraViewFrame inputFrame) {
    mRgba = inputFrame.rgba();
    //mGray = inputFrame.gray();
    Mat mZoomWindow = mRgba.submat(140,320,100,380);
    Imgproc.resize(mZoomWindow, mRgba, mRgba.size());
    wsize = mZoomWindow.size();
    Scalar color = new Scalar(255);
    Imgproc.rectangle(mZoomWindow, new Point(1, 1), new Point(wsize.width - 2, wsize.height - 2), color, 2);
    //Mat mask = new Mat(mZoomWindow.size(), CvType.CV_8U);
    Mat mask = Mat.zeros(mRgba.size(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
    /*boolean use_harris = true;
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2GRAY, 4);
    Imgproc.goodFeaturesToTrack(mRgba, features ,100, 0.01, 10, mask , 8, use_harris , 0.06);
    List<Point> drawFeature = features.toList();
    for (int i = 0; i < drawFeature.size(); i++){
        Point p = drawFeature.get(i);
        Imgproc.circle(mRgba, p, 5, new Scalar(0,255,0));
    }
    //Imgproc.cvtColor(mIntermediateMat, mRgba, Imgproc.COLOR_GRAY2RGBA, 4);
    //mIntermediateMat.convertTo(mRgba, CvType.CV_8UC4, 1); */
    Imgproc.cvtColor(mRgba, mRgba , Imgproc.COLOR_RGBA2RGB, 4);
    featureDetector.detect(mRgba, keyPoints);
    Features2d.drawKeypoints(mRgba, keyPoints, mask);
            return mRgba;
}
```

}
`

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what you're trying to achieve and what is going wrong?  Are you trying to get the drawing of circles and rectangles working, identification of features from the camera feed, etc...?

Comment: First of all thankx that u came on this page and commented. I am gratefull that u gave time to my question. My problem is that i want to detect the features that come in the area of tht rectangle and i want to detect optical flow of those points lying in area of that rectangale. Basically i am building application for Blind people for indoor movement. I think what i am doing wrong is that i must use Surface Holder for this. Can u please help me in my problem and guide me. As i am a final year student of software engineering

Comment: This question is sounding a bit broad at this point.  Stackoverflow isn't a help desk for homework assignments.  You're going to have to put some effort in yourself and identify key areas that you're having trouble in.

Comment: i just want to know how to get feature points from a specific area in a video stream? Is that possible?

Answer (score 0):

May be I am too late now and most probably you have done it already. But from what I understood, you need to process the video frame by frame. So when you get a frame, you can crop it to get a Mat object of the marked rectangular area only. Then you can detect the feature points in the cropped image and match them with the feature points of the an object that's on the road giving red points(you can have a local picture of that thing on the road to give you the feature points of it. By the way, what is that thing?).

But this is for tracking within the rectangle using KeyPoints. If you want optical flow, again, detect the points and store them, then use optical flow algorithm in the cropped image.